# ASP.NET MVC: WHY ValidateInput(false) works only when the postback action and controller are explicit on the Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

The whole weekend, I've been learning how to use TinyMCE with ASP.NET MVC. I was getting the XSS error ("*A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client(...)*").

To deal with that, I was advised to use the ***[ValidateInput(false)]*** attribute to release the checking, but without success. Until, by accident, I did a postback to a different action method (i.e. not the one that displayed the view containning TextArea control). so I have to explicit both the Action and the controller. IT WORKED. So I tried to **explicitly** declare the BeginForm for the first case, then, IT WORKED AGAIN.

The question is **WHY**

```
<%Using(Html.BegiForm()){%>
```

or

```
<%Using(BeginForm("WriteArticle"))%>
```

both did not work.

```
<%Using(Html.BeginForm("WriteArticle", "ArticleManagement")){%>
```

This one worked.

So, Why the famous "**Convention over configuration**" didn't work?

**EDIT**

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public class ArticleManagementController:Controller
{     
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //Here model is created and updated
  }
  public ActionResult WriteArticle()
  {
    //Here's the method that displays the View containing the TinyMCE editor
  }

  //There are more action methods
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the name of the controller which contains the action responsible for rendering this view (not the one you are posting to)?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: the action is WriteArticle, the controller is ArticleManagementController.

Comment: Could you show the code of this controller? Only the signatures, no need to know the details of the actions.

Comment: I just updated the posted. I hope I gave the information needed.

Comment: Are form URLs (actions) same in both cases (in the page HTML), with explicit/implicit BeginForm?

Comment: @Queen3: Actually, the WriteArticle is the action that renders WriteArticle View, so I'm supposed to <%Using(Html.BeginForm()){%>, right? well, it doesn't work, giving the XSS error I talked about in the post. But, when I wrtite <%Using(Html.BeginForm("WriteArticle", "ArticleManagement")){%>, then it works.

Comment: No, I meant, what is the actual URL in the page HTML in the browser, in both cases. Also are other form tag attributes different in both cases.

Comment: For both http://localhost:49158/ArticleManagement/WriteArticle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.BeginForm()` does *one* thing. IT generates HTML. So if one overload works and the other does not, then *they are generating different HTML*. View source of the rendered page. They will be different. This is most likely tied to your routing or your view execution path, but it's hard to be sure without seeing the HTML and your code. The important point is this: When your server reacts differently, you are almost certainly sending it a different request. View Source and Firebug's Net panel are the two tools you should start with.

Comment: There's a bad news. I've playing with the view and action that generates (by adding and removing [ValidateInput(false)] here and there). Now, I don't know anymore what went wrong. I have now removed the action and controller's names, but it still working. So I don't know what went wrong anymore.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for you answer about Html.BeginForm what is the answer to my preoccupation. Now, I know that I need to pay attention to the url generated by a request. Also, your advice on View Source and FireBug.